# XSL namespaces and nested xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

I have below XML and would like to iterate through the element as such the i could display it in some format like:

```
PIN 1<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  XYZ<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  HELLO<br/>

PIN 2<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  ABC<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  HI<br/>
```

XML:

```
<RootResponse xmlns:ip="urn:domain:tx:inPayment" xmlns:ipn="urn:domain:tx:Pin">
   <OutBoundMessage>
      <ip:InfoMessage>
        <ipn:Alert>PIN 1</ipn:Alert>
         <ipn:Code>
           <ip:CodeLabel>XYZ</ip:CodeLabel>
           <ip:CodeMessage>HELLO</ip:CodeMessage>
         </ipn:Code>
      </ip:InfoMessage>

      <ip:InfoMessage>
         <ipn:Code>
           <ipn:Alert>PIN 2</ipn:Alert>
           <ip:CodeLabel>ABC</ip:CodeLabel>
           <ip:CodeMessage>HI</ip:CodeMessage>
         </ipn:Code>
      </ip:InfoMessage>
  </OutBoundMessage>
</RootResponse>
```

I Can't seem to find a solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following the [W3C schools XSLT tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), this should give you all you need to solve this relatively simple XSLT problem.

You are right that you will have to pay attention to namespaces, although again this is quite straightforward. Simply ensure that your XSLT defines the namespaces required, and that you prefix element names in your XPath statements accordingly. See the following:

[XML Namespaces and How They Affect XPath and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the namespaces in your XSLT and then use the declared prefix in your expressions.

Below is an example of how to do that, using templates(i.e. "push style") rather than `xsl:for-each` (e.g. "pull style").

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ip="urn:domain:tx:inPayment"
xmlns:ipn="urn:domain:tx:Pin"
exclude-result-prefixes="ip ipn">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="ipn:Alert">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ip:*[starts-with(local-name(),'Code')]">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```